# share data between two proccess (cant create proccess)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ofstream

I am trying to write a program that use two proccess, one is only allowed to open the text file and mapping him into the ram but not change the memory, and the other one is only allwed to use the mapped memory and change the memory but not mapping him-self. **The purpose of the whole program is to open a .bin file and change the first letter into "Z".**
I got an error when trying to create the second procces.
Someone know what is the problem?.

this is the procces of the program

- main.cpp open the file, mapping him into the ram and then create proccess that changing the first letter.
- second cpp file is only changing the file first letter

this is my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    SYSTEM_INFO info;
    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    LPSTR buffer;
    int memory = 0;

    GetSystemInfo(&info);
    memory = info.dwAllocationGranularity;

    hFile = CreateFileA("gibrish.bin",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
    hMapFile = CreateFileMappingA(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, "sourceFile");
    
    buffer = (LPSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, memory);

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    BOOL p = CreateProcessA("replaceZ.exe", buffer, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi); // here I get the error
    if (p)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    UnmapViewOfFile(buffer);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

this is the second code / "replaceZ.exe":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, LPSTR sentBuffer)
{
    LPSTR buffer = sentBuffer;
    LPCSTR letterToReplace = "Z";   
    buffer[0] = (CHAR)letterToReplace;
    return 0;
}
```

the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Please include errors as text. That's important, so people can search for the error online, which is another thing you should do.

Comment: Your code assumes (a) `CreateFile` worked. (b) `CreateFileMapping` worked. (c) `MapViewOfFile` worked, and (d) the mapped file content contains a *terminated* string that can be passed to `CreateProcess` as the command line argument (2). Apart from the obvious (checking for errors rather than blindly assuming all of the above somehow work), running your code in a *debugger* and checking what is about to be passed to `CreateProcess` would be highly advised.

Comment: If you are using **both** the first and second argument of [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) you're going to have to understand the implications. Specifically that the CRT isn't going to magically resolve the conflict of you passing **two** arguments that can be interpreted as the first argument passed into `main`. It's also not going to magically resolve the conflict of interpreting a pointer that's valid in one process to have any kind of meaning in a different process.

Comment: Add to that, and argument of `LPSTR sentBuffer` isn' even valid for `argv` in `main` anyway, which must be `char *argv[]`, not `char*`. Your second program is ill-formed.

Comment: You should use `CreateProcess` in this way: `CreateProcessA(NULL, "Command line you want to run, it can be path to exe file", ....);` and second param should be a writable char array

Answer (score 0):

As [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709653/share-data-between-two-proccess-cant-create-proccess#comment125003280_70709653) said, What's the meaning about passing one process address to another process?
To share data between two processes, there is a document sample [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory).